# How to get text from span that is not in Latin Alphabet?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm having difficulty getting text between `span` tags. The problem is that the said text is not written in Latin Alphabet.

I have no problems using UTF text as part of `xpath` locator. My `xpath` looks like this: `//span[starts-with(., 'Пријем')]`

Selenium finds that element, clicks on it, but when I want to retrieve text from that `span` I get `?????? ?????? ??????????`.

The `span`in question looks like this:

```
<span class="ui-menuitem-text">Активне резервације</span>
```

I'd really appreciate a bump in the right direction.

Comment: What happens if you try to compare the element text with Активне резервације? Assert.assertEquals(element.getText(), "Активне резервације")

Comment: It asserts to `true`. I've managed to change Eclipse environment encoding to UTF-8, I'm struggling with TestNG. If I change the `expected`condition the test fails but the trace is not in UTF but an incomprehensible mess...

Comment: If the assert passes, it means the problem is only configuration of your env to display the text - the Selenium code is working properly. I'm voting to close the question as unrelated to testing then.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is environment configuration, not testing.